# How to prove or calculate $E[\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} e^{-μ({t_i}-s)}\sigma B_s |x_{t_{i-1}}]=0$?

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, gaussian-integral

$B_s$ is brownian motion. Because $\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} e^{-μ({t_i} -s)}\sigma dB_s  $ has a Brownian component, it is normally distributed with the mean zero according to Taylor & Karin 1998 's Introduction to Stochastic Modelling.

The above expectation is derived from the ornstein uhlenbeck model:
$$dx_{t}= μ(θ-x_t)dt+\sigma B_t  $$

and if  $x_{t_i}$ given  $x_{t_{i-1}}$.

$$ e^{μ{t_i}}x_{t_i}=x_{t_{i-1}}+ \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} μe^{μs}θds + \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} e^{μs}\sigma B_s  $$

$$\iff x_{t_i}=x_{t_{i-1}}e^{-μ{t_i}}+ θ(1-e^{-μΔt}) + \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} e^{-μ({t_i}-s)}\sigma B_s  $$

where $Δt={t_i} - t_{i-1}$

Based on Leung & Li 2016's Optimal Mean Reversion Trading, the distribution of $x_t$ given  $x_{t-1}$ under the Ornstein Uhlenbeck model is  normally distributed with
$$E[x_{t_i}|x_{t_{i-1}}]=x_{t_{i-1}}e^{-μΔt}+ θ(1-e^{-μΔt})$$

$$ Var(x_{t_i}|x_{t_{i-1}})= \frac{\sigma^2}{2μ}(1-e^{-2μΔt})$$

So $$E[x_{t_i}|x_{t_{i-1}}]=x_{t_{i-1}}e^{-μΔt}+ θ(1-e^{-μΔt})+E[\int_{t-1}^t e^{-μ(t-s)}\sigma dB_s |x_{t_{i-1}}]=x_{t_{i-1}}e^{-μΔt}+ θ(1-e^{-μΔt})$$ so that means
$$E[\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} e^{-μ({t_i}-s)}\sigma B_s |x_{t_{i-1}}]=0$$

How do I prove/derive this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $M_t := \int_0^t e^{-\mu(t_i-s)}\sigma dB_s$ and note that $M_t$ is a martingale because it is a stochastic intgerlad with a locally bounded integrand.  By linearity of the stochastic integral, $\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} e^{-\mu(t_i-s)}\sigma dB_s = M_{t_i}-M_{t_{i-1}}$ and hence
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_i} e^{-\mu(t_i-s)}\sigma dB_s|x_{t_{i-1}}] = \mathbb{E}[M_{t_i}-M_{t_{i-1}}|x_{t_{i-1}}] = M_{t_{i-1}}-M_{t_{i-1}} = 0.
\end{align*}
There's a bit swept under the rug here (like the fact that $x_t$ is a Markov process and generates the same filtration as $B_t$), but that's basically it.

Comment: How to prove that $M_t := \int_0^t e^{-\mu(t_i-s)}\sigma dB_s$ is Martingale? I know the Brownian motion itself is Martingale, but in this case the Brownian motion is the $dB_s$ inside the integral, what should I do? Thank you!

Comment: How to show that the integrand is locally bounded? Thank you!

Comment: @KennethTheodore The fact that stochastic integrals are martingales is typically one of the first properties shown after defining the integral.  It can even be taken as part of the definition.  You should be able to find a proof of this fact in any book that defines the stochastic integral.  As for showing the integrand is locally bounded, note that $0 \le e^{-\mu(t_i-s)} \le e^{-\mu(t_i-T)} < \infty$ for any $s \in [0,T)$ and $T < \infty$.